# Do not mutate Vuex outside mutation handler. How to reactively update an array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

My goal is to mutate the array's object reactively, I want it to update whenever I call this action on my component

Index.vue

```
<select @change="onChange($event, product)">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

```js
onChange(event, product) {
   let qty = event.target.value
    // Assuming product is an object { _id: 23, quantity: 23 }
   this.$store.commit("changeQuantity", {product, qty})
}
```

store/index.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  cart: [
          {"_id": 1, "quantity": 2}, 
          {"_id": 12, "quantity": 4},
          {"_id": 9, "quantity": 99}, 
          {"_id": 3, "quantity": 14}
        ]
});      
export const mutations = {
 changeQuantity(state, { product, qty }) {
    // Find a targeted product in the cart
    let cartProduct = state.cart.find(item => item._id === product._id);
    // Find the Index
    let indexOfProduct = state.cart.indexOf(cartProduct);
    // Change the quantity
    cartProduct.quantity = qty;
    // Create a new copy and assign it to the same variable
    cartProduct = Object.assign({}, cartProduct);
    // Removed and update with a new object, Reason why I use splice is because
    // of the reactivity
    state.cart.splice(indexOfProduct, 1, cartProduct);
  },
}
```

The first time is okay, but the second time it shows an error

> [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

What is the industry standard to mutate an array and update it immediately?

Comment: why do you set the quantity before `Object.assign()`?

Comment: I think it's unlikely the error comes from the code in your question since there is nothing happening outside the mutation

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the code provided ~ https://jsfiddle.net/hLfr46tn/